# StyleCop raises SA1600 warning for protected member in sealed class

Tags: c#, .net, stylecop

I was wondering if there was a real reason for StyleCop to report a SA1600 warning for a missing documentation header on an overridden protected member in a sealed type.

Since the type is sealed, it can't be inherited from. And since it can't be inherited from, then why would anyone bother writing a documentation header on its overridden protected members?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: That's StyleCop, not FxCop (aka code analysis).  The brain-damaged child.  Just don't use it if you don't like what it says, it is only a tool for teams that have members yelling at each other about what somebody else's code should look like.

Comment: @HansPassant StyleCop, that's right. I edited the post, thanks. I *do* like this tool a lot and I want to keep using it. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious. Judging by your comment, I'm guessing I'm not; it's actually StyleCop that is (as I thought).